# How to find the Root Cause and fix this NullPointerException at Context.getApplicationInfo() when activity is started

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crashlytics, stack-trace, runtimeexception

I have got this crash for an activity in my app, have effectively large count.

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference


Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:191)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getTargetSdk(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2975)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2964)
   at android.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:89)
   at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:8016)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3751)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3977)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:109)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2374)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
```

We have tried to reproduce this by opening the activity form all possible sources, all deep links, normal user actions , not able to reproduce it.

I also have checked that findViewByID is not called before OnCreate() as found to be the cause of other crashes in stackoverflow.

I also want to know more about how to connect All Thread Info in the stackTrace. I guess it is the status of all threads at the time of the crash.

What are the different possible causes to throw the above NPE?

Looking at the stack trace can we be certain that the application has crashed before any of the lines in onCreate is executed?

ANother Stacktrace -

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MerchantProfileDetailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3651)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3808)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2221)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7952)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
```

Basically The crash is thrown by :

```
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3808)



 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3598)
```

And in the full stacktrace never any line of code of app class is mentioned.

I don't know how to fix this?

PLease help me with your thoughts!

Comment: share your code instead of logs

Comment: not sure, how much of the code should i share?

Comment: by the stacktrace, I think, Its evident that OnCreate must not have started executing, an?
please correct me If i am wrong?
@AmanGrover

Comment: Are you trying to call any activity methods when intialising fields in an activity? I.e. `final View v = findViewById(...)` ?

Comment: No @PPartisan
and in that case, it would point to the line number of that findViewByID code, wouldn't it

also I added more info.
IN my case, it does not point to any line number of the activity class.

Comment: If the issue is still not resolved (hope it is resolved ), try checking if there is any `getApplicationInfo` in the code. Activity, Fragment, or Application class code.